# Gitlab CI UI tests

Tags: android, continuous-integration, automated-tests, gitlab

I'm trying to run my UI tests using the Gitlab CI but something is apparently wrong.
I don't have that much experience so I might be missing something very silly.
I found this snippet to run my tests but it doesn't work.

```
- wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
- chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
- android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator" "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
- echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
- android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -verbose -show-kernel -avd test -no-window -no-audio -no-accel -no-snapshot -gpu swiftshader_indirect &
- ./android-wait-for-emulator
- adb shell input keyevent 82
- ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Do you know how to fix this? I tried to google everywhere but I didn't find anything helpful enough.

I tried already:
https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/20/working-with-yaml-gitlab-ci-android/
and some other links but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the error message / log output ?